# Improving time complexity of finding triplets

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

The program in question is to find the number of triplets in an array/list with a given sum.

My approach has been to first sort the array and then use the two-pointer technique to find such triplets. The overall time complexity turns out to be O(n^2).

Is there any way how I can further improve the time complexity?.

Comment: can you please supply your code? i find it hard to wrap my head around the fact that you manage to sort the array and execute the two pointer technique in O(n log n): comparison-based sorting uses at least O(n log n), the two pointer technique needs O(n), but you should be doing the two pointers in some kind of nested loop in order to find triplets, right? that would bring the total to at least Ω(n^2)

Comment: Oops ... That's a typo. It runs in O(n^2) actually. Is it possible to make some changes to bring the complexity down to O(n log n)??

Comment: yes, that's what I suspected. I don't think its possible to improve that runtime complexity any further, but I can't think of an intuitive argument right now. I am also unable to find better approaches online.

Comment: a related problem is the 3SUM (that asks whether there exists at least one triplet that sums to some value) and apparently it is an unsolved question whether it is solvable in O(n^{2-epsilon}) time, for some epsilon > 0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

Comment: therefore, if the answer to your question was yes it would directly imply the 3SUM problem being solvable in O(n^{2-epsilon}) and therefore the answer to your question is likely to be no, it is not possible. if you do find a solution however be sure to let the world know, because you would embed your name in the computer science history books I reckon

Comment: @D3PSI... That's quite an eye-opener ... I didn't even realise I was asking a very deep question. Thanks for furnishing the information.